# Custom log4j class not printing the class Name From where the Log is written

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have **Custom logger Class** `mycust.log.LoggerLog4j.java`, whenever I want to log any message I will use like `Log.info("Some Message")`. Say I am writing this line in `com/TestLog.java` at line `10` in method `printLogTest()`.

**Current Log:**

```
2013-10-30 16:32:50,528 INFO  [main] [45:mycust.log.LoggerLog4j.java][log] - Some Message
```

**Expected Log:**

```
2013-10-30 16:32:50,528 INFO  [main] [10:com.TestLog.java][printLogTest] - Some Message
```

**Log4j.properties entry:**

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] [%L:%C.%F][%M] - %m%n
```

**Log4j version :**

```
`log4j-1.2.14.jar`
```

**LoggerLog4j.java:**

```
private static void log(Priority p, Object o, Throwable t) {
        try {
            Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(this.className);
            logger.log(p, o, t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Logged to sys to avoid infinite cycle
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905611/printing-the-source-class-in-a-log-statement-with-a-log4j-wrapper

Comment: a static void log calling "this.className" ? "this" is not supposed to be visible in a static method, is it ?